# Is there any way to return the failure from a PowerShell script into azure CLi?

Tags: azure, powershell, jenkins

I'm tryig to build a Jenkins pipeline that controls a Windows Virtual Machine in Azure. I need to run some Powershell scripts on that VM using Azure CLI. The problem that I'm having is that Azure CLI is returning the operation as successful even when the PowerShell script fails.

Here is a run when the script fails and the pipeline passes:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "code": "ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "level": "Info",
      "message": "Uninstalling the previous version\n\nCheck that the previous installer was uninstalled\n\n'App' NOT is installed.\n",
      "time": null
    },
    {
      "code": "ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "level": "Info",
      "message": "C:\\Location\\clean_up.ps1 : Exception of type \n'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException' was thrown.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\1.1.5\\Downloads\\script49.ps1:1 char:1\n+ & C:\\Location\\clean_up.ps1\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,clean_up.ps1\n ",
      "time": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I was not able to find any way to return the error from PowerShell to the pipeline making the pipeline unusable. Is there a way I can Is there any way to make Jenkins Pipeline fail?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, better option would be to go with Azure PowerShell. However, in current scenario, to return the actual code from PowerShell, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798043/passing-the-actual-return-code-from-powershell) helps.

Comment: Thanks, for the answers. I was not able to send something similar to `powershell.exe -Command ". C:\MyScript.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE"` using Azure CLI and Jenkins. 
Also trying to start Azure Powershell in my docker-compose seems more difficult than expected.